# VB.NET desktop application error : Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version = 1.2.10.0 Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 692fbea5521e1304'

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, windows-8.1

I've setup a VB.NET desktop application in a Windows 8.1 pro 64-bit PC. After doing server configurations I'm trying to login to the application. It's when I'm getting the following error message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version = 1.2.10.0 Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 692fbea5521e1304'or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I've installed SAP Crystal Reports 13.0.3 64-bit yet it's still not working.

What is the reason behind this problem?

Comment: making one click application?

Comment: @utility Didn't get your question.

Comment: done using setup project ?

Comment: @utility, I'm sorry, I described the scenario wrong in my question. I've updated it. Please have a look.

Comment: I'm downvoting for the "urgent so expecting a quick answer", and because you have nine other questions where you are asking for priority over other questions. Please be aware that all questions have equal importance here, and are answered by volunteers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

The problem raised due to the mismatch in version of the log4net.dll file. My solution had log4net version = 1.2.9.0, while it needed the version = 1.2.10.0, hence the exception occured. I replaced the existing log4net.dll file with the one which has appropriate version and the problem was solved.

Comment: If you answer your own question - don't forget to accept the answer so the question is not considered unsolved.

Comment: Captain, would you award the acceptance to yourself here? To do so, click on the tick mark to the left of the answer, so that it turns green. This is how we mark questions as resolved, and we encourage self-accept answers (though if someone else did most of the work it is generally good to give them the tick).

Answer (score 2):

Check you Application files in Project Settings,find status of log4net dll whether included or not .Make it included in your project as below :

[image]